# items are not being added

Tags: java

When the items in my hashmap are being printed [see code starting with `for (Map.Entry<String, World> entry : WorldsByName.entrySet())......`], only the last item that I have added gets printed out. The others disappear.

```
.....

        public interface World {
            abstract void run(String s);
        }

        private void sample(String[] inserted) {
            Map<String, World> WorldsByName = new HashMap<String, World>();
            WorldsByName.put(inserted[1], new World() {
                public void run(String s) {
                    if (inserted[0].equals("house")) {
                        System.out.println(inserted[0] + " with name " + s + " has been created.");

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("What do you mean by " + inserted[0] + " ?");
                    }
                }
            });

.....
```

Comment: this code should give compilation error...  `if inserted[0].equals("house"))` in the implementation of `void run(String s)`, you cant just use `inserted[0]` here. `inserted` isn't `final`.

Comment: What does inserted array contains, did you try to print it in your sample method?

Answer (score 0):

Your code only puts single value in WorldsByName map

```
WorldsByName.put(inserted[1], new World() ...
```

So when you are trying to execute for loop it will execute for only one key value.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, World> entry : WorldsByName.entrySet()) {
```

**Edit:**

For your requirement you will need to `change the method structure` or you will have to `make WorldsByName as global variable`. For loop is not required for your use-case.

For changing method structure:

```
 private void sample(String[] inserted, Map<String, World> WorldsByName) {
```

Pass instantiated WorldsByName from caller method, do not initialize(`new`) it in sample method. Make sure to add null checks and all in sample method for inserted and WorldsByName.

For making WorldsByName as global variable:

```
Map<String, World> WorldsByName = new HashMap<String, World>();

private void sample(String[] inserted) {
    // Map<String, World> WorldsByName = new HashMap<String, World>();
    WorldsByName.put(inserted[1], new World() {...
```

If you are going to create multiple instances of HashMapTest2 class then don't make WorldsByName as static otherwise you can also make WorldsByName as static

Comment: You have to put all the keys in your map and corresponding value.

Comment: thats very true... it's only inserting the item at index 1 of your String array

Comment: It will not create any problem, just make a note of my last statement in the answer. And if you find this answers your question then you can accept it by clicking check mark.

Answer (score 0):

You could try inserting all items at once but the value will be an object signature..

```
 static Map<String, World> WorldsByName = new HashMap<String, World>();

 private void sample(final String[] inserted) {

    for (int i = 0; i < inserted.length; i++)
        WorldsByName.put(inserted[i], new World() {
            public void run(String s) {
                if (inserted[0].equals("house"))
                    System.out.println(inserted[0] + " with name " + s
                            + " has been created.");
                else
                    System.out.println("What do you mean by " + inserted[0]
                            + " ?");
            }
        });
    for (Map.Entry<String, World> entry : WorldsByName.entrySet())
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":-->" + entry.getValue());

  //..your other code here..
  }
```

and make that parameter final but I'm not sure what exactly your trying to achieve here except this will insert a value for a key in format like **defparser.HashParser$1@b1c260**

Comment: Why are you checking `if (inserted[0].equals("house"))` for every value in HashMap i.e. why only 0th position?

Comment: I am asking @EagleOne, for the comment he added in your answer.

Comment: `Map<String, World> WorldsByName` is method scoped, so whenever you pass new value of inserted into sample method, it will create new HashMap for WorldsByName, resulting loss of previous values.

Comment: I am doing it this way because later I want to be able to paint the houses by using their name as reference. For e.g when I type command "california red", it will paint the house with name "california" red; if I type "chicago blue", the house with key "chicago" gets painted blue and so on... I want to create many houses and then be able to modify them by using their key in the hashmap.

Comment: Oh! The HashMap are being overwritten!

Comment: so you could create a Hashmap (static Map<String, World> WorldsByName = new HashMap<String, World>();) as a static global variable then use it in the method  **void sample(final String[] inserted)** you can choose your access modifiers. See edit

Answer (score 0):

I assume, according to your previous comments that you will pass only two paameters, one is house/hut/etc. and second is name. Therefore, you are using inserted[0] and inserted[1].
This is fine as long as you only care about two parameters.
To retain the values in map, There are multiple ways:
1) Create HashMap as instance variable and use same object to call sample method. For eg:

```
    class HashMaptest2{
        Map<String, World> worldsByname = new HashMap<String, World>();
        etc.
    }
```

In main method

```
psvm(){
HashMapTest2 test=new HashMaptest2();
test.sample(inserted1);
test.sample(inserted2)
```

2) Second way is to create HashMap in your main class and pass it to sample method as Naman pointed.